# Displaying same username for all users with a specific role as comment author

Tags: 8, users, comments

I need to display the same username for users of a specific role as comment author.

I have a Role 'Board Moderator'. When users with this role are commenting, a uniform name 'OneUserNameForAll' should be displayed as author of a comment.

How can I get this done?

Comment: Can you just change the author uid of that comment on submit if the user is in a certain role?

Comment: It is not possible to have duplicate usernames, see [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/73454/is-it-possible-to-allow-duplicate-usernames) post

Comment: I don’t think the ask is for duplicate usernames. Hence the suggestion to just change the UID on comment submit.

Comment: Changing the UID is a good idea. So far I was thinking of using the real name or another field from user profile.

Comment: How can I change the UID of an author on submit? I tried rules but there's no action to change the author.

Comment: Why not simply handle this in the way comments are displayed, ie. in the theming layer? Other solutions seem to overcomplicate the issue.

Comment: I already tried to do that in templates. But I couldn't get it done to get the author field data. I tried to check comment authors role to simply overwrite it hard coded.
Can someone tell me how to check authors role in comment templates?